# How do PhD students buy equipments in Germany?

Tags: phd, funding, germany

What mechanisms do German public universities have for funding research equipment?

E.g., suppose a PhD student at a German public university needs a GPU-enabled computer or laptop for their research work.

How can they fund that? Do universities have any funding mechanism?

Comment: There is information missing: In comments below you state that you don't study in Germany. So why ask about Germany?

Comment: This question is unclear.

Usually universities have different infrastructures, and students there can book time of the infrastructure. No need for PhDs to know how university funds its infrastructure. For example, a GPU-computer would be a cluster computer (example: https://wiki.uni-jena.de/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=22453005 ) and the student can book time on a similar cluster there (example: https://wiki.uni-jena.de/display/URZ010SD/HPC-Cluster+Draco )

Comment: We are trying to help you, but cannot do so without the necessary information. You not being there puts you at a disadvantage, so we must know why that is. If you don't tell us, then we cannot help you. Not because we don't want to, but just because it is impossible.

Comment: Another piece of information we need is: are you self-funded, or do you receive a stipend for the university, or are you employed by that university?

Comment: Honestly taking the comments by left by the user into account this sounds like "I'd like someone to buy me a gaming laptop". Add to this the Germany tag, even though the user isn't in Germany just makes it more confusing. I'm in the UK, if you need a GPU you'll get access to a centrally managed one, no-one will buy you one for your own personal use only.

Comment: That is a bit weird. In order to help you we need to know your real problem not a hypothetical one. If you are doing your PhD in Narnia, then knowing how things are done in Germany does you no good.

Comment: The more probable reason is that you did not go through "proper channels". Remember, that universities are big bureaucracies, and escalating like you did is a very serious thing to do. You breaking those rules reflects badly on him, and he does not like it.

Comment: Anyhow, the real problem has now become "how do I start communicating again with my supervisor after I goofed up like that". This is completely different from what your original question is, so it is better to start a new question

Comment: Inquiries are better done verbally. Whatever is on paper (or email) has a risk of becoming formal.

Comment: That is simple: you are not going to get one. Your advisor was very clear about that. Now you need to think outside the box: How can you use other resources that are available to you, to do your research. Various suggestions were already put forward to you in the comments.

Comment: That was not one of the suggestions, but hey it is your money after all.

Comment: Perhaps if you were asking about the country you are actually in you could get advice about systems in the country that actually affects you.

Comment: As pointed out by the second comment, many universities have their own policies on how IT-infrastructure money is to be spent (e.g. no parallel structure building, buy computing hours instead of gpus). This could also include giving out already purchased laptops first, and/or capping the money that can be spent on new laptops. While PhD students are commonly provided with a laptop to use, this isn't a "gift"- it belongs to the department.
tl;dr Talk to your supervisor, adjust your expectations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funding comes from two possible places the University/department or external funding agencies via grants. Who funds what depends on what's being funded, how much funding is needed, and who the money is benefiting. For (large) equipment purchases it can also be the case that external grants require the University to pay part of the cost while the external grant covers the rest. It may also be the case that there is no existing funding now, but funding can be applied for to support your research needs.

However, as a PhD student, none of this is your concern. You just need to ask your supervisor. If they think you need the equipment, they will then work out in consultation with the department where the money is going to come from.

Comment: @user366312 If you need a specific computer for your research it is not personal equipment. This might mean that it formally isn't your property and you have to return it to the lab at the end of your studies.

Comment: As a phd student, there should be funding for a PC or laptop. It might be difficult if you already have a computer to get another one. So if you don't have anything then I would contact the person in charge of all phd students in your department to raise a complaint. If you have something already then you may be out of luck. The other option if you just need a GPU is to talk to the local IT technicians on how you can get access to a local computing cluster or would know what you need to do to apply to external computing clusters.

Comment: @user366312 Obviously you have to go to your supervisor first. It seems like they do not agree that such a laptop is really needed for the research.

Comment: This is quite rare, but if the PhD is funded by a scholarship, there may be some budget for (smallish) equipment like a laptop, books, ....

Answer (score 6):

Yes, in general the mechanism is "ask your professor".

Comment: Sorry for bringing reality in your life.

Comment: The professor would not pay for it herself/himself/themselves. Either you are part of a project that is externally funded, in which case they (more often, their secretary) manages those funds. Or there are some department level funds they can access. Or ... But none of these options are open to you, they all have to go through the professor.